# Extracting DAY, WEEK, MONTH, YEAR from a date column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this, named `Tour Details`.

| dealdate | Tours | Weeknumber | Country | SubVenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-12 | 3 | 49 | India | SP1 |
| 2022-11-25 | 4 | 48 | India | SP2 |
| 2022-10-14 | 5 | 42 | India | SP3 |
| 2023-01-05 | 3 | 2 | India | SP1 |
| 2023-01-05 | 4 | 2 | India | SP2 |
| 2023-01-06 | 5 | 2 | US | SP1 |
| 2023-02-24 | 3 | 9 | US | SP2 |
| 2022-02-12 | 4 | 7 | US | SP3 |
| 2023-02-19 | 5 | 8 | US | SP1 |
| 2023-02-27 | 6 | 10 | US | SP2 |

I need to create a table `summary tour details`.
This table should have information like the `DAY`, `WEEK`, `MONTH`, `YEAR` derived from the `dealdate` from `Tour Details` for every record in the column `SubVenue`.

| Grp | Day | Week | Month | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tours SP1 | 1 | 49 | 12 | 2022 |
| Tours SP2 | 3 | 50 | 11 | 2023 |
| Tours SP1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2022 |
| Tours SP3 | 12 | 4 | 2 | 2023 |

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `MySQL` <> `SQL-Server`

Comment: How come `SP1` appears twice in the resulting table if you do a group by? And whence does the Week 50 for Tours SP2 come from? Your question/specifications are unclear to me.

Comment: Can you show us your current query attempt?

Comment: Do you want to see one row for each date, or one row for each country + subvenue?

Comment: @Swifty ,I edited the question as I realised it was posed incorrectly. let me know if the task is clear now

Comment: @RobEyre one row for each date is what I am looking for

Comment: *"let me know if the task is clear now"* You've yet to correct your tags, so it still not clear what (R)DBMS you are using.

Comment: @ThomA Using sql-server

Comment: Have you had a look at `DATEPART` or the `DAY` and `YEAR` functions?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example for datatype `date`. But it will also work for `varchar`.

```sql
create table [Tour Details](
  dealdate date,
  Tours int,
  Weeknumber int,
  Country varchar(100),
  SubVenue varchar (5)
)

insert into [Tour Details]
values
('2022-12-01',  3,  49, 'India',    'SP1'),
('2022-11-25',  4,  48, 'India',    'SP2'),
('2022-10-14',  5,  42, 'India',    'SP3'),
('2023-01-05',  3,  2,  'India',    'SP1'),
('2023-01-05',  4,  2,  'India',    'SP2'),
('2023-01-06',  5,  2,  'US',   'SP1'),
('2023-02-24',  3,  9,  'US',   'SP2'),
('2022-02-12',  4,  7,  'US',   'SP3'),
('2023-02-19',  5,  8,  'US',   'SP1'),
('2023-02-27',  6,  10, 'US',   'SP2')

select 'Tours '+SubVenue as Grp, 
       datepart(day,dealdate) as [Day],
       datepart(week,dealdate) as [Week],
       datepart(month,dealdate) as [Month],
       datepart(year,dealdate) as [Year]
into [summary tour details]
from [Tour Details] 

select * from [summary tour details]
```

[image]